# What is the general form of the valid polynomial equations over $\mathbb Q$ relating $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\alpha=i$, $\beta =-i$, $\gamma=\sqrt{2}$ and $\delta=-\sqrt{2}$ and consider the permutations

$$R=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta&\gamma&\delta\\\beta&\alpha&\gamma&\delta\end{pmatrix},~S=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta&\gamma&\delta\\\alpha&\beta&\delta&\gamma\end{pmatrix}.$$

I need to prove that the permutations $R$ and $S$ preserve every valid polynomial equation over $\mathbb Q$ relating $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$.

Some of these valid polynomial equations are

$$\alpha^2+1=0,~\alpha+\beta=0,~\delta^2-2=0,~\gamma+\delta=0,~\alpha\gamma-\beta\delta=0$$

We see that $R$ and $S$ preserve them, but I don't know what is the general form of these polynomials, in order to show that $R$ and $S$ preserve them. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: You may realise that $P_1(X)=X^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and so you would get $\alpha^2+1=0$(because it is a minimal polynomial), $\alpha+\beta=0$ (sum of roots is equal to the coefficient of $x$) and the same goes for $P_2(X)=X^2-2$. 

You may also say that $\alpha \gamma=\beta \delta$ and $\alpha \delta=\beta \gamma$ satisfies the minimal polynomial $X^2+2=0$ which yields the last relationship

Comment: @daruma But these are not all the valid polynomial equations. I want to show that $R$ and $S$ preserve all the valid polynomial equations.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, I am going to rewrite things a little bit:

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\delta)$

Let $R: K\to K$ defined by $\alpha\mapsto -\alpha$ and $\gamma\mapsto \gamma$

Let $S: K\to K$ defined by $\alpha\mapsto \alpha$ and $\gamma\mapsto -\gamma$

Now $G=\langle R, S\rangle $ is a group of order $4$.

You may try to prove that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$ (Not too difficult). Note that this is actually a normal extension and separable extension(characteristic of $K$ is clearly $0$ as it is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$) It is in fact a Galois extension.

Then, $G=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$. If we want to look at all the fixed elements under $G$, you may recall from FTGT that 
$K^G=\mathbb{Q}$(fixed field of $G$.) So in particular, $p(\alpha,\gamma)\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $p(X,Y)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ , it means $R$ and $S$ maps $p(\alpha,\gamma)$ to itself.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I didn't study the Galois group yet, so that I'm looking for an elementary way.